# Trying to dynamic import via React.lazy using a variable string

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, import

Using React.lazy to dynamic import component through variable string contains it's path
like this:

```
const product_map = './DVD'

const Product = React.lazy(() => import( `${product_map}`));
```

and in the return

```
<Suspense fallback={<></>}>
<Product></Product>
</Suspense>
```

it shows me this error

```
./node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/@testing-library/dom.esm.js 456:27
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (456:27)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition -- types are not aware of older browsers that don't implement `labels`
|   if (element.labels !== undefined) {
>     return element.labels ?? [];
|   }
|
```

I tried using this form Template literals and straight using the variable it's not rendered via React.lazy()
except straight string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
The issue was i was not configured right the bable loader and its plugins in order to load JSX components from a dynamic variable contained the name of component.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).